# Can a company ask if you have autism when applying for a job?

Tags: interviewing, job-description

I recently saw a job post that had the following section inside it:

> Candidate Should be US Citizen
>
> Candidate Should have **Autism Spectrum Disorder**
>
> Job Type: Full-time
>
> Required experience:
>
> - Software Development: 1 year
>
> Required education:
>
> - Bachelor's

The bold section is the concerning part.  Can a company really specify that a candidate has this condition, and can they ask during the interview about it?

Comment: If you want to ask a legal question, you need to include the jurisdiction. Also, there is a high chance of having the question closed as we don't generally do legal advice (except for really basic questions)

Comment: It's not really a legal question, mostly a curiosity thing

Comment: Obviously they can ask the question; you just quoted them doing it. If it's not a legal question, I'm not sure I understand what you want to know.

Comment: They asked it, so, yes they can

Comment: There are cases where a company can recruit based on attributes that would otherwise be forbidden. Normally the reasons are 'because it is necessary for the job'. An obvious example is that a company looking for an actor to play a caucasian male is allowed to say 'caucasian male' in the advert, and exclude people who are not. This might well be one of those cases.

Comment: Does the job deal with autism or accessibility, or disabilities in any way?

Comment: @user70848 doesn't say that in the rest of the job dec.

Comment: @Kilisi For the most part I think you are too "in your face" but that was good.

Comment: @paparazzo my English isn't good so I try to be direct and understandable, you mistake that for 'in your face'.

Comment: @Kilisi Telling me it is my mistake is 'in your face'.  Your English is not that bad.

Comment: That's discrimination in most countries. The same way they can't ask if you have Autism and stop you having the job if you do.

Comment: I'm slightly more concerned with the US Citizen requirement, that might be discrimination since all that's usually required is that they be allowed to work in a given jurisdiction this could include visa holders who are not citizens. (Assuming this is in the US)

Comment: @GlenPierce It could be a requirement because they're working on government systems, or something that requires ITAR

Comment: It's possible that the position is specifically meant for someone on the autistic spectrum as the result of a government or private grant program.  As the father of two high-functioning autistic sons, I would very much welcome this kind of position.